# Change Current cell in Cell Enter Event of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a form with `datagridview`.

The result I want is:

- When user clicks on ReadOnly Cell, the Cursor will move to Editable Cell.
- When user clicks on Editable Cell, the Cursor will be on this Current Editable Cell.

I make this on `Cell_Enter Event` (I have some reason to code this on `Cell_Enter`.I have to use Cell_Enter).

```
DataGridViewCell cell = myGrid.Rows[cursorRow].Cells[cursorCol];
myGrid.CurrentCell = cell;
myGrid.BeginEdit(true);
```

Clicking on `Editable Cell` is OK, Clicking on `ReadOnly Cell` give an Exception Error:

Error->
**Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.**

So, Is there a solution for this problem? (When user clicks on `ReadOnly Cell`, the Cursor will move to `Editable` Cell.)
**Edit**:The solution I want is How do I move cursor to Other cell that is not Current cell?

Comment: Maybe you can do a `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");` in case of cells which are readonly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/vcexpressja/thread/9bd773b3-652f-44a6-bc03-ddf74713a781).

```
      private void myGrid_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do stuff
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);

        }

        void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
            myGrid.CurrentCell = myGrid[cursorCol,cursorRow];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `If.. else ..statement`

```
if (cursorCol == 1) //When user clicks on ReadOnly Cell, the Cursor will move to Editable Cell.
{
   myGrid.CurrentCell = myGrid[cursorRow, cursorCol];
}
else //When user clicks on Editable Cell, the Cursor will be on this Current Editable Cell.
{
  //Do stuff
  myGrid.BeginEdit(true);
}
```

Comment: The solution I want is How I move cursor to Other cell that is not Current cell?

Comment: try to `dataGridView1.CancelEdit();` before you want click another cell

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this will work in your situation, but I once ran into something like this due to one of our client's silly UI requirements. The quick fix was wrapping the code in `BeginInvoke`. For example:

```
BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = myGrid.Rows[cursorRow].Cells[cursorCol];
    myGrid.CurrentCell = cell;
    myGrid.BeginEdit(true);
});
```

Essentially this will make it execute the code after the `CellEnter` event, allowing the `DataGridView` to do whatever it does behind the scenes that was causing the exception.

Eventually it was refactored into a custom control that extended `DataGridView` and `BeginInvoke` was no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.This answer may be solve the problem, but I have already found a solution last night and I posted it as answer. I will accept it as answer tomorrow.